# Chat Application Database Query and Design

Tags: php, mysql, database-design, database-schema

[this is my database scheme with the query below.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PK9DD.png)

this is the scenario that confuses me.
when i login as user_id = 1 and create a conversation and the receiver is user_id = 4 the query below works.. because the query to retrieve the conversations is based on the sender. Now when I log in as user_id = 4 I can't see the conversation because I'm the receiver and I don't want to create another conversation where I'm the sender and the receiver is user_id = 1 because the conversation was started by user_id = 1. can anyone help me with the query?

Answer (score 1):

Change your Inner Join to include the receiver as well, so

```
INNER JOIN
conversations ON (userprofiles.user_id = userprofiles.receiver_id OR userprofiles.user_id = sender_id)
```